# How do I prevent the compiler from compiling obvious typos like if (somevalue = 0)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2022

I have once seen and used a helpful setting in Visual Studio that prevented the compiler from compiling obvious typos like

```
if (somevalue = 0)
```

I do not find this setting anymore in VS2022.

What is the name of setting?

It was not the Code Analysis feature, but rather an option that really prevented this from being compiled.

Comment: If you can't find the setting, you can try to add to your source files (maybe via a common include): `#pragma warning( error : 4706 )`.

Comment: In settings `C/C++->General->Treat Warnings As Errors`

Comment: @user20716902 this won't work unless warning 4706 is active.

Comment: You're right,, this setting triggered on a different warning

Comment: In settings -> C/C++ -> Advanced -> Treat specific warnings as errors : fill `4706`.

Comment: Thanks, I found it under Project-><projectname> settings.

Comment: Right click the solution in the solution pane and select Properties, its the Configuration Properties

Comment: When I select "Yes (/WX)", it even considers this as not-compilable: "    if( ( ::GetVersionEx( &ver ) == TRUE ) && (ver.dwPlatformId == VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT) && ( ver.dwMajorVersion >= 6 ) )"

Comment: Do I need to enter a certain "Warn version"? Currently it's blank / empty.

Comment: The suggestion provided by @wohlstad is probably the best approach here, use `C/C++ -> Advanced -> Treat specific warnings as errors`, just enter the value of `4706`

Comment: What do I select in "Warn level" where I can choose between W1, W2, W3 and W4?

Comment: I have mine set to W3

Comment: When I type 4706 behind "Treat specific warnings as errors", it says that this option is of type Boolean.

Comment: All the big 3 produce warnings for me and I could add treat warnings as errors if I wanted to - live - https://godbolt.org/z/3qhd47bMz  For MSVC set warning level to 4.

Comment: @tmighty are you in the "advanced" tab ? there is also a global "Treat Warnings as Errors" under the "general" tab (which is indeed boolean). The option I;m refering to is in the advanced tab: Treat **Speific** Warnings as Errors.

Comment: @wohlstad Thank you, your setting did it. Settings the other warnings only caused super weird warnings.

Comment: I still have one problem with this setting: It won't compile utility-> (line 214) anymore: ": first(_Tuple_get<_Indexes1>(_STD move(_Val1))...), second(_Tuple_get<_Indexes2>(_STD move(_Val2))...) {}"

Comment: It can be found in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\include\utility

Comment: I resolved it by settings the general "Treat warnings as error" to "No" again.

Comment: Most modern compilers have settings (disabled by default) to issue warnings on things like `if (somevalue = 0)`.   You'll need to read documentation for your compiler to find them.    One somewhat common technique to trigger a diagnostic (compilation error) is to reverse the order of operands so the constant value is on the left e.g. `if (0 = somevariable)` will trigger a diagnostic, but `if (0 == somevariable)` will not. That reordering doesn't work if *both* operands are variables though, since the assignment is then valid within rules of the language (hence still need for warning options).